# MySQL Event for deleting data if 5 years has passed

Tags: mysql, events

How can I use an Event in mysql to check if data is more than 5 years old and then delete that row is statement is true?

I've tried the following but with no luck

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `Delete_data_after_5_years`
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
COMMENT 'Clean up GDPR data at 1 AM.'
DO
  DELETE FROM b2sjcwjexw158glf.customer
  WHERE registered < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
```

My data/database looks like this (Don't mind the data, it is just test data)
[image]

Comment: What it the problem precisely? the event procedure code itself looks like correct one. The only point - I should use `WHERE registered < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 YEAR`.

Comment: @Akina I'm just confused on the Interval part. Does that mean it will automatic calculate from the given date(registered) if 5 years has passed?

Comment: No, backward, the date which is 5 years ago is calculated, and the `registered` is compared with this date.

Comment: The delete statement is not terminated in the published code - did the code syntax and compile?

Comment: @P.Salmon I get an error saying "No database selected" when executing the code

Comment: Not with you, you cannot execute an event

Comment: @P.Salmon I mean, when I try to compile the code to create the event I get that error messages.

Comment: You need to point to the db that you want to attach the event to probably using USE <dbname> before attempting to compile. And for testing I suggest you change the interval to something smaller than 1 day.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yeah like I do here "DELETE FROM b2sjcwjexw158glf.customer". But I can't figure out where I attach the db to make it registre when compiling?